# geemap - add text to Landsat time series and change the pace of images

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, text, geemap

I'm trying to generate timeseries from Landsat images [based on the documentation of geemap](https://geemap.org/notebooks/18_create_landsat_timelapse/#create-landsat-timeseries).

**The problem:**

**'frames_per_seconds' parameter:** When I create time series without the years as text, seems like this parameter works, but when I add the text, it runs too fast

I was trying to add the gifs here but it's too heavy

This is how I generate the time series:

```
collection = geemap.landsat_timeseries(
    roi=fct, start_year=1985, end_year=2022, start_date='01-01', end_date='12-31'
)

# Define arguments for animation function parameters.
video_args = {
    'dimensions': 768,
    'region': fct,
    'framesPerSecond': 3,
    'bands': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'],
    'min': 0,
    'max': 0.8,
    'gamma': [1],
    'frames_per_seconds': 3
}

work_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Downloads')
if not os.path.exists(work_dir):
    os.makedirs(work_dir)
out_gif = os.path.join(work_dir, "/home/keller/git/my_noteboook/nbs/project/downloads/landsat_ts.gif")

geemap.download_ee_video(collection, video_args, out_gif)

geemap.show_image(out_gif)
```

[image]

This creates image that runs in the pace I have defined (3 per seconds) ,

However, when I add the text **it becomes too quick:**

```
texted_gif = os.path.join(work_dir, "landsat_ts_text.gif")
geemap.add_text_to_gif(
    out_gif,
    texted_gif,
    xy=('3%', '5%'),
    text_sequence=1984,
    font_size=30,
    font_color='#ffffff',
    add_progress_bar=False,
)

geemap.show_image(texted_gif)
```

[image]

As you can see, it runs way to fast than the original gif. I tried to add the frames_per_seconds to the add_text_to_gif but it doesn't have this parameter.

The polygon I have used:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "fake",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "fid": 1, "id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 28.992940449603836, 12.18029140886693 ], [ 29.088260210846986, 12.231815604133496 ], [ 29.081819686438664, 12.131343423363692 ], [ 28.973618876378875, 12.121038584310378 ], [ 28.992940449603836, 12.18029140886693 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

**My end goal: add the years (text) and have the original pace.**

Comment: So what happens when you reduce the framesPerSecond parameter to say 1?

Comment: on the first image it works but on the 2nd when I add the text it goes back to high speed

Comment: So just to be absolutely clear no matter what is set for framesPerSecond the GIF stays at the speed of the 2nd image?

Comment: @AWGIS yes, this is what happens

Answer (score 0):

For the [add_text_to_gif](https://geemap.org/timelapse/?h=add_text_to_gif#geemap.timelapse.add_text_to_gif) you can control this using the `duration` parameter. The reference mentions the following:

> controls how long each frame will be displayed for, in milliseconds. It is the inverse of the frame rate. Setting it to 100 milliseconds gives 10 frames per second. You can decrease the duration to give a smoother animation.. Defaults to 100.

So if you want 3 frames per second as you did with the `landsat_timeseries` function, then choose `duration=333` (which would give you 3.003003... frames per second -- close enough).